# Displaying names as links using Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I can drop a message and share a link to someone's wall using Facebook graph API. 
However as if in http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=114961875194024&id=7901103 , I want the names as a link. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: I want to show every name in users friend list as links, when you click them it takes you to their profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, retrieve your friends like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=2227470867|2.EHCI04eO2X4n4cxQlvnS2Q__.3600.1305194400.0-100001037215362|3ABwjZygEj8OZS2247vzgDoLyr4
```

Now, you only have to pair the names with their IDs like this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/FRIEND_ID">FRIEND_NAME</a>
```

If you want to make a function that transforms a text with Friends names use regular expressions.